# Ping sweep LAN without specifying IP

Tags: linux, nmap

I know I can ping sweep my LAN by doing something like `nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24` which works just fine.

I was wondering if there was anyway `nmap` could figure out the range for the local subnet on it's own, using my LAN IP and Netmask, without me having to specify the IP range.

Does NMAP have such a feature?

In the case it doesn't, can this be achieved with a bash line on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip route` is probably the easiest way to get this information and is correct in most situations.

```
root@myhost:~# ip route 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.30
```

Here's a not-very-elegant-and-could-use-more-work shell command that will extract the `192.168.2.0/24` that from the above.  It will extract the above and put it in the shell variable `$MY_SUBNET_WITH_CIDR`

```
DEFAULT_ROUTE_IFACE=`ip route | grep default | cut -f 5 -d " "`; \
MY_SUBNET_WITH_CIDR=`ip route | tail -n -1 | grep $DEFAULT_ROUTE_IFACE | cut -f 1 -d " "`
```

Of course, if your default gateway is provided by your cable modem or home broadband provider, you'll be trying to `nmap` a network belonging to them, which could look hostile, so be careful.